# Association analysis for methylation beta value and phenotypes in R

Tags: r, bioconductor, statistics, epigenetics

I am trying to learn how to do association analysis of methylation array data with numerical trait like body weight, eGFR.
As I have seen some of the publications, methylation data association with eGFR has been showed through regression analysis but I am not sure how to run regression for so many CpG probes in R.

Can you have look on this below publication and could you help with R code for regression analysis?

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01297-7.pdf

I do have methylation beta value from RnBeads but I am not sure how to read methylation data (rows/column-CpG/SampleID) and then how to read phenotype data file and finally how to make single sheet to run regression analysis?

Comment: Have a look at this method https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/34/15/2657/4939328

Comment: Hi, I found a way to do methylation data association analysis with eGFR as shown here (https://support.bioconductor.org/p/93868/), but not sure how make input files; like in methylation data file; do I take CpG probe as rows or column? and I am also not sure how to mention covarites in modal.matrix for eGFR association? Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

*Answer from @user4939328, converted from comment. Please improve this answer if you can:*

Have a look at this method:

https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/34/15/2657/4939328

*[Wondering why this was converted from a comment? See the StackExchange rules about comments [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)]*